# What is going on in the first stanza of Audre Lorde's "Never to Dream of Spiders"?

Tags: poetry, audre-lorde

The first half of the first stanza of Audre Lorde's "[Never to Dream of Spiders](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/42584/never-to-dream-of-spiders)" goes like this:

> Time collapses between the lips of strangers
> my days collapse into a hollow tube
> soon implodes against now
> like an iron wall

All four of these lines indicate that the narrator feels like time is out of whack. However, I'm at a loss as to how even to *begin* to interpret the next half of the stanza, which goes like this:

> my eyes are blocked with rubble
> a smear of perspectives
> blurring each horizon
> in the breathless precision of silence
> one word is made.

So... what exactly is going on here? Why are the narrator's eyes "blocked with rubble" - does this indicate crying? What's the "precision of silence", and what's the "one word" that is made? And what does all this have to do with the time distortion in the first half of the stanza?

Comment: There's a bunch of different interpretations [here](https://msknarrbooknook.proboards.com/thread/37/never-dream-spiders-audre-lorde) that might be interesting. Btw, grats on 16k rep!